# How to do inter process communication(communication b/w 2 JVM's on same server) using vert.x

Tags: java, tomcat7, ipc, vert.x

I need some guidance. I have implemented vert.x(1.3.1.final) using eventbus mode in my web application. Currently, what am I doing is whenever a event is generated on server, the notification sent to the client/clients associated with that unique address.Everything is going fine.

Now, in my web application, some certain process takes all resources of tomcat and than tomcat gives OutOfMemoryError. So, my team decided that the process taking large number of resources will be separated from web application(i.e. outside tomcat).

So now requirement is to communication between two java processes that is executing on separate JVM on same server.

Is it possible with vert.x? I didn't get so much help regarding inter process communication using this. Or I will have to use other methodology like (the techniques using java inter process communication.) ?  What would be the best solution in terms of performance.

Answer (score 3):

Two vert.x processes on the same server can communicate using the built-in Event Bus, if you start each process using -cluster and set ports accordingly.  See the examples included with the distribution.

You might also consider looking at vertx 2.x rather than 1.3.1...

Comment: Two vert.x processes means, two different JVM's ?
It means, will I have to implement multiple vert.x server on same machine to resolve my problem?

Comment: Yes, that's what you stated in your requirement. "So now requirement is to communication between two java processes that is executing on separate JVM on same server."

Comment: You can use the processes in different servers. All you have to do is configure vertx cluster accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For specifically your case, I can see that [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) would be a best fit.

You can also use [Java Management Extensions (JMX)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/index.html) to expose methods in a running process through a simple web interface.